# ng-pattern error message not displaying

Tags: angularjs

hi i am new to angular js i have an aspx page in which i have a div tag which consists of login div and other div tags

i have set ng-app and ng-controller to main div tag and i have used update panel and scriptmanager and above this there is a form tag.
But when i try to show a div on a invalid pattern the div does not get displayed
below is my html

```
 <body onload="heightpx()">
        <form name="form1" runat="server">

            <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>

            <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                <ContentTemplate>

                    <div id="chatwindow" ng-cloak ng-app="s" ng-controller="sChat" class="col-md-4 col-xs-12" style="height: 100%; position: absolute; padding: 0px; float: right; bottom: 0px; right: 0px; z-index: 10001; background: #FFF; border: 1px solid #898989">
     <div id="loginform" class="col-md-11 col-xs-11" ng-show="Islogin==false && ExistingCustomer==true" style="margin-top: 5px;">
                        <div class="form-group">

                            <input type="text" ng-model="Name" name="Name" placeholder="Name" class="form-control" id="uname" onkeyup="euname();" required ng-pattern="/^(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}/" />

                            <div class="custom-error" ng-show="form1.Name.$error.pattern">Not a valid subnet, should be i.e. 10.x.y. (3 bytes only)</div>
                        </div>
                   </div>
              </div>

                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </form>
    </body>
```

Comment: There is no loginForm in your code. So the expression `loginform.Name.$error.pattern` is always undefined. Your form is named "form1", and it's out of the angular app anyway.

Comment: by mistake form name got changed,plz check i have edited

Comment: Your <form> tag is out of the angular application. So Angular doesn't care about it. Move ng-app and ng-controller above, on the body or html tag.

Comment: tried that but didnot work

Comment: Define "didn't work", precisely. What did you do, what did you expect to happen, what happened instead? Post all the relevant code and error messages.

Comment: i placed ng-app and ng-controller in html body and form one by one and checked all the possible ways but desired feature of  ng-show="form1.Name.$error.pattern" not working,ideally when i enter wrong pattern ng-show should return true,but ng-hide remains

Comment: Works fine here: http://plnkr.co/edit/jAY94LXHsjcPubKtFWWe?p=preview. Type "1", the error appears. Type "1.2.3.", the error disappears.

Answer (score 0):

Your Form1 is outside the scope of angular. Therefore angular compiler doesnt read that form. 
You can create form tag(loginForm) inside angular app and then use loginForm.Name.$error.pattern. It should work

Comment: Can you create a plunker for that.